# What simple multi channel amp rack do you recommend?

Tags: monitoring

For monitoring I need to drive sound of multiple soundcards into one and single amp with 4 inputs and 4 outputs

No routing, input 1 goes to output 1, and so on.

My speakers (4): 15-100w 8ohm FR 90Hz-20kHz (+-3dB) 87dB

Could you recommend me a simple solution ?

Something like the unit below would be great. But it's a unit for headphones and I think it won't provide the 100w I would like to send to the speakers.

[image]

http://www.berhinger.com/EN/Products/HA4400.aspx

Comment: should be tagged soft-question

Comment: @Skliwz - What's that?

Comment: Unfortunately all of the inexpensive rack-mount, powered mixers on the market appear to be stereo (two 100 watt channels), so you would need two units to get four channels.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks. I've been told a simple car audio amp could do it. Regardless the impedance. So I'll try that, and if it doesn't work, I'll buy that Brad suggests below.

Comment: @neilfein: a way of tagging questions with no objective answer

Comment: @Pierre 303, and how would you power your car audio amp?  Don't do this.  It will be more expensive for you to build or buy a proper power supply, and your quality won't (generally) be that great.

Comment: @Brad: I have tons of adapters that convert 220V AC to 12V DC.

Comment: @Pierre 303, at high amounts of current?  Well, never mind then.

Comment: @Brad: You may be right. http://www.ehow.com/how_6145028_power-watt-car-amp-house.html. I still have to investigate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ART SLA4](http://www.artproaudio.com/products.asp?type=85&cat=8&id=140) should meet your needs.  Not the cheapest amp around, but it fits in one rack unit and is of high quality.

[image: ART SLA4]
[image: ART SLA4 Rear]

If that is too expensive for you, just plug in whatever amps you like that aren't.  You don't need to run all four channels in one amp.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Behringer Eurorack RX1602. It's simple and cheap (100£) and does the job.

http://www.berhinger.com/EN/Products/RX1602.aspx
[image]

Comment: Nice machine, but it has only 1 output (stereo). I need at least 4. And 4 inputs.

Comment: I don't understand, if you have four channels at line level, what's preventing you from plugging them in directly in the amp? How many line ins do you need to mix?

Comment: As stated in the original question: no routing. (So no mixing.)